# The 'op' operator in SML

Tags: sml

So I came across with the `op` operator and I don't get the pupurse.

I defined two functions:

```
fun op pow1 (x,y) = Math.pow (x,y);
fun pow2 (x,y) = Math.pow (x,y);
```

They both have the same signatures:

```
val pow1 = fn : real * real -> real
val pow2 = fn : real * real -> real
```

And they both have the same function calls:

```
pow1 (5.0,6.0);
> val it = 15625.0 : real
pow2 (5.0,6.0);
> val it = 15625.0 : real
```

So what is the difference between those two functions? What is the idea behind `op`?

Answer (score 4):

The `op` keyword undoes the infix status of the following (alphanumerical or symbolic) identifier. For example:

```
val n = op+ (1, 2)            (* equivalent to: val n = 1 + 2 *)
val m = op mod (5, 6)         (* equivalent to: val m = 5 mod 6 *)
fun op+ (x, y) = x - y        (* equivalent to: fun x + y = x - y *)
```

These lines would be syntax errors otherwise.

This is useful when referring to a normally-infix function without immediately invoking it, such as when passing it to a higher-order function. For example:

```
List.foldr op+ 0 [1, 2, 3]    (* equivalent to: 1 + (2 + (3 + 0)) *)
```