# How to add all elements in a list in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to add all elements in a given integer list and finally return an integer as its sum

Following is the code I have tried

```
val intList = [1,2,3,4];

fun addList (list) = 
let
  val head = List.hd list
  val tail = List.tl list
  val sum = ref 0
in
  if(list <> [])
  then sum := !sum + head
  addList(tail)
  else !sum
end;
```

However, I am getting the following error

> Elaboration failed: Type clash. An expression of type "'a" cannot have type "(('a → 'b) → 'c → 'd) List.list" because of circularity.

I am quite new to SML/NJ
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You should not be using `ref`, `:=`, or `!`. Forget about those other languages you're familiar with and learn like you've  never written a program before, starting with the basics.

Comment: The type issue is that `!sum + head addList(tail)` is one expression, and it tries to apply `head` as a function to `addList` and `tail`. But you should not try to fix it, you should start over.

Comment: Note also that this calls `List.hd` and `List.tl` on a list _before_ determining if it is empty.

Comment: @Chris what would you recommend to do then? The same problem I got as mentioned by molbdnilo appears again with some other error in the then statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was looking into a different problem and I found a solution for this one as well.

```
val intList = [3,7,5,6];

fun addList (list, x)=
if list = []
then x
else
let
  val head = hd(list)
in
  addList(tl(list), x + head)
end;


val something = addList(intList, 0);
```

It is similar to how the foldl operation works, but ofcourse different in terms of use.

I didn't know we could pass an element this way as an argument to the function. This was interesting.

Comment: A better version of that approach would be something like `local fun helper (nil, x) = x | helper (h :: t, x) = helper (t, x + h) in fun addlist list = helper (list, 0) end`. That way callers don't have to pass in the meaningless-to-them `0`. (I've also taken the liberty of some other cleanup, making the code more ML-ish and less of a translation from an imperative language.)

Comment: @ruakh Wow! That works! I am yet to reach the 'local' keyword. Hence I don't fully understand what it does or why it's used here. However, I did understand the overall logic. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! And — `local` is like `let`, except that instead of an expression (let *declarations* in *expression* end) it's a declaration (local *declarations* in *declarations* end). It prevents `helper` from being visible to later code that doesn't need it. It's not essential, but it helps keep the environment clean.

Answer (score 3):

You're far along the wrong track - you shouldn't even be thinking about references or assignments.
(In fact, you're probably never going to use them.)

Here is the general idea - it is very straightforward to translate into SML:

The sum of a list is

- If the list is empty, it is zero
- Otherwise, add the head of the list to the sum of the tail of the list.

Note that there are no variables and no assignments anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should reduce the entire list into single element using binary operation. In Standard ML you can do this using `List.foldl` function.

```ml
> val sum = List.foldl op+ 0 [1, 2, 3, 4];
val sum = 10: int
```

This essentially puts + between consecutive elements and evaluates to

```ml
> val sum = (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4;
```

`op+` is a way to pass an operator to a function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54814038/5956245

https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.foldl:VAL

Comment: At the OP's level of understanding of SML and functional programming, it would be helpful to demonstrate how `foldl` can be implemented (it's not a long chunk of code). Of course, this also requires explaining tail recursion...

Comment: Here's an example of [foldl implementation from PolyML](https://github.com/polyml/polyml/blob/326b50a52421358c8b7ee4b37f4fed5cd329f1ca/basis/List.sml#L117-L118)

Comment: @Serpent7776 I must say that that example only confused me more. I am working on CPN-ML and not SML/NJ to be honest. CPN-ML takes its programming from SML/NJ entirely, so I'm learning to apply it there.

Comment: @Serpent7776 That said, I did understand by taking your answer, testing it on the SOSML compiler. I also took reference from the link you had shared in your main answer

Answer (score 0):

To answer the comment asking about using `List.hd` and `List.tl` *before* checking whether `list` is empty, this can result in an exception, and because the recursion converges on the empty list case, *will* result in an exception. We need to do this *after* that check. Fortunately `let ... in ... end` is an expression and can be used anywhere an expression is expected. So now:

```
fun addList(list) = 
  if list <> [] then
    let
      val head = List.hd list 
      val tail = List.tl list
      val sum = ref 0
    in
      sum := !sum + head;
      addList(tail)
    end
  else 
    !sum;
```

Now we don't have `sum` bound in the `else` branch. This gives us a compilation error. So, let's modify this again.

```
fun addList(list) = 
  let
    val sum = ref 0
  in
    if list <> [] then
      let
        val head = List.hd list 
        val tail = List.tl list
      in
        sum := !sum + head;
        addList(tail)
      end
    else 
      !sum
  end;
```

But the problem here is that `sum` is bound to a different reference to `0` on each recursive function call. Calling `addList` on any list will yield `0`. We would need a recursive function which operates on the *same* `sum` reference by binding that name in an outer scope which an inner function will enclose.

```
fun addList(list) = 
  let
    val sum = ref 0

    fun aux(list) =
      if list <> [] then
        let
          val head = List.hd list 
          val tail = List.tl list
        in
          sum := !sum + head;
          aux(tail)
        end
      else 
        !sum
  in
    aux(list)
  end;
```

Of course, what if we don't use `List.hd` and `List.tl` at all but substitute pattern-matching, which is much more idiomatic.

```
fun addList(list) = 
  let
    val sum = ref 0

    fun aux(list) = 
      case list of
          [] => !sum
        | head::tail => (
            sum := !sum + head;
            aux(tail)
          )
  in
    aux(list)
  end;
```

Or more concisely:

```
fun addList(list) = 
  let
    val sum = ref 0

    fun aux([]) = !sum
      | aux(head::tail) = (
          sum := !sum + head;
          aux(tail)
        )
  in
    aux(list)
  end;
```

Of course the proper way to write this is to avoid the use of `ref` entirely, as mutable state is non-idiomatic in this situation, and entirely unnecessary. The use of a fold, as already suggested handily avoids tail-recursion and means that no matter how large a list we sum, we'll never encounter a stack overflow.